# Filtering after Grouping ExtJS column throws "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5, extjs-grid

- I am working on ExtJS 5.0.1 Grid,where when **I apply grouping on it
  and later filtering on the same column** I am getting the following
  error which says "**Maximum call stack size exceeded**".
- I haven't wrote any code for it as it is a default functionality of
  ExtJS.Can anyone say **if this is a Bug in ExtJS?** Any solutions?

["Maximum call stack size exceeded"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwSzg.png)

Comment: can you add code snippet to your question?

Comment: Can you try to get a minimal working sample in a fiddle? What happens if you then switch ExtJS version in fiddle to e.g. 5.1.2?

Comment: Its occuring in ext-all-debug.js.Its a very large file as u know and i dont know which code to place.All am doing is trying to debug the file based on  the error messages shown in the image.But still no result.